# Changing color of Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I took this code from another post, however it won't work for me. The tooltip (including arrow) should be blue, but they are staying black.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

```css
.tooltip-primary + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner { background-color: blue; }
.tooltip-primary + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
 
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
       title="Tooltip on bottom"
       class="tooltip-primary">Tooltip on bottom</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `+` selector -- remember, that's the **adjacent** sibling combinator, meaning that the target needs to come **immediately** after the element you're referencing. This is not the case with the Bootstrap tooltip; it gets injected at the **bottom of the DOM**.

It is still a sibling in this particular example, so you can target it with the **[general sibling combinator `(~)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)**, simply replacing your `+` with `~` (tilde):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

```css
.tooltip-primary~.tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: blue;
}

.tooltip-primary~.tooltip>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom" class="tooltip-primary">Tooltip on bottom</a>
```

However, note that if your anchor is not at root level (which is highly likely), then you will **not** be able to use CSS to target the tooltip, as there is no notion of a parent selector in CSS.

Comment: I see this works, but when I try it in my app, it's still default black. I really don't understand your explanation.

Comment: The problem is that in your app you probably have something like `<div><a data-toggle></div>`. The tooltip will become a sibling of the **`<div>`** in this case. Because your initial CSS target is the `<a>` tag, you would need to 'traverse up' a level and target a sibling of the parent `<div>`. Unfortunately, this is impossible in CSS, as there is no parent selector (you'd want something like `div:has(.tooltip-primary)~.tooltip`). In such a context, you'll need JavaScript unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution if anchor is not at root level**

If your anchor is not at root level, the only way I've found that works is using the inserted.bs.tooltip event and adding a class to the inner div and the arrow.  Then you can target the class in css.

```js
// initialize tooltips
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 

// Add the classes to the toolip when it is created
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('inserted.bs.tooltip',function () {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.tooltip-inner').addClass(thisClass);
    $('.arrow').addClass(thisClass + "-arrow");
});
```

```css
/* style the tooltip box and arrow based on your class*/
.bs-tooltip-left .redTip {
    background-color: red !important
}
.bs-tooltip-left .redTip-arrow::before {
    border-left-color: red !important
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>Show a red tooltip <a href="#" class="redTip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="You Did It!">Hover over me</a></p>
```